# Adding image over another image - bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to add an image over an image.

For example, there's an image in the background and on top of that i need to add an image of a `play button`. Where the user can play the video by clicking on it. This is also shown on the `Shopify` homepage.

```
<!-- Wrapper for slides -->
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="item active">

                    <img width='100%' 
                        src='http://roomista.com/uploads/hotel-gal/250_SunwayHotelHanoiSuperiorRoom.jpg' />
                <div class='img-container'>
                    <div class='img-text'>
                        <img src="http://lizkhoo.com/content/play-icon.png" alt="..." />
                    </div>

                </div>
```

And the CSS is as follows:

```
.img-container {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 10px 5px 5px;
}

.img-text {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: You are going to want to give the `.img-text` a `position: absolute;` and then set the `top` and `left` properties accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Use position: relative on .item and position: absolute on .img-text.
You should not need to use z-index on .img-text, but if it appears under .img-container, use it.

```
.img-text {
    /*position: absolute;*/ Wrong, see edit
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    /*top: ?; bottom: ?; left: ?; right: ?; //to place it as you want.*/
}

.item{
    position: relative;
}
```

**Edit** : I misread your code, (badly indented :p)

```
<!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active">
            <img width='100%' 
               src='http://roomista.com/uploads/hotel-gal/250_SunwayHotelHanoiSuperiorRoom.jpg' />
            <div class='img-container'>
                <div class='img-text'>
                    <img src="http://lizkhoo.com/content/play-icon.png" alt="..." />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

So position: absolute on .img-container

```
.img-container {
    position: absolute;
    top: ?; bottom: ?; left: ?; right: ?; //to place it as you want.
}
```

**Edit 2 :** 
A little jsFiddle, like the comment below :  http://jsfiddle.net/hsYwV/1/

Comment: A quick thing that i noticed, When i shrink the page how can i maintain the position of the video icon to be at the centre on the image?

Comment: @Illep, if you want it to stay in the center of the containing image, just set all of the properties to 0, i.e., top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;

Comment: @Illep, Here's a fiddle to demonstrate: http://jsfiddle.net/jme11/3yL45/  I wasn't sure if you needed the img-text for something else so I left the mark up, but it's not needed to center the image in this example.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to set the image as a background.

html:

```
<div class="item-active">
        <img class='img-text' src="http://lizkhoo.com/content/play-icon.png" />
      </div>
```

css:

```
        .item-active {
                width: 200px;
                height: 200px;
                background-image: url('http://roomista.com/uploads/hotel-gal/250_SunwayHotelHanoiSuperiorRoom.jpg');   
    }


.img-text {
        position: relative;
        left: 75px;
        top: 75px;

        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
      }
```

JScript:

```
$(".img-text").bind("click", function(){
          alert("play video");
           });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/J7qnF/2/

Comment: A quick thing that i noticed, When i shrink the page how can i maintain the position of the video icon to be at the centre on the image?